# How do I put a single backslash into an ES6 template literal's output?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, escaping, read-eval-print-loop, template-literals

I'm struggling to get an ES6 template literal to produce a single backslash it its result.

```
> `\s`
's'
> `\\s`
'\\s'
> `\\\s`
'\\s'
> `\\\\s`
'\\\\s'
> `\u005Cs`
'\\s'
```

Tested with Node 8.9.1 and 10.0.0 by inspecting the value at a Node REPL (rather than printing it using `console.log`)

Comment: Same as every other string literal. `\`\\\`  === "\\"`. It's just the REPL representation that is confusing you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get your question right, how about `\\`?

I tried using `$ node -i` and run

```
console.log(`\\`);
```

Which successfully output a backslash. Keep in mind that the output might be escaped as well, so the only way to know you are successfully getting a backslash is getting the character code:

```
const myBackslash = `\\`;
console.log(myBackslash.charCodeAt(0)); // 92
```

And to make sure you are not actually getting `\\` (i.e. a double-backslash), check the length:

```
console.log(myBackslash.length); // 1
```

Comment: I *think* that it's the console.log function that's doing the interpretation of the first backslash as an escape char there, rather than the template literal... but I'm not sure that'll work for me as I'm using it to create a regex in a SQL statement (don't ask why!).

Comment: I was testing at a node repl, just evaluating those template strings and looking at the resulting value, rather than printing the output

Comment: Keep in mind that the output of a `console.log` or the output of REPL will be escaped as well. Please see [this example on Runkit](https://runkit.com/barbu110/backslash-out-of-a-template-string)

Comment: Aha! Didn't think about the REPL escaping, that's it! Calling `length` on the results also shows they are actually a different length than they appear when you've got multiple sequential `\` chars

Comment: Glad I could be of use!

Answer (score 5):

It is a known issue that [unknown string escape sequences](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JS/Useless+regular-expression+character+escape) lose their escaping backslash in JavaScript normal and template string literals:

> When a character in a string literal or regular expression literal is
> preceded by a backslash, it is interpreted as part of an escape
> sequence. For example, the escape sequence `\n` in a string literal
> corresponds to a single newline character, and not the `\` and `n`
> characters. However, not all characters change meaning when used in an
> escape sequence. In this case, the backslash just makes the character
> appear to mean something else, and the backslash actually has no
> effect. For example, the escape sequence `\k` in a string literal just
> means `k`. Such superfluous escape sequences are usually benign, and do
> not change the behavior of the program.

In regular string literals, one needs to double the backslash in order to introduce a literal backslash char:

```js
console.log("\s \\s"); // => s \s
console.log('\s \\s'); // => s \s
console.log(`\s \\s`); // => s \s
```

There is a better idea: use **`String.raw`**:

> The static **`String.raw()`** method is a tag function of [template
> literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). This is similar to the `r` prefix in Python, or the `@`
> prefix in C# for string literals. (But it is not *identical*; see
> explanations in [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5016).) It's used to get the raw string form
> of template strings, that is, substitutions (e.g. `${foo}`) are
> processed, but escapes (e.g. `\n`) are not.

So, you may simply use `` String.raw`\s` `` to define a `\s` text:

```js
console.log(String.raw`s \s \\s`); // => s \s \\s
```

Comment: `String.raw` did it for me, thanks!

Comment: [MDN link for `String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) (aka, if you were wondering, it is legit/baked in/[vanilla at some point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw#browser_compatibility), which was implied, but not made explicit, in this answer.)